# Custom table creation options in django models

Tags: django, mariadb

I have a girl model (i mean django =)

```
class Girl(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

  first_name = models.TextField()
  last_name = models.TextField()
  nickname = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  maiden_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=

  about = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  quotes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  activities = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  books = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  games = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  tv = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  interests = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  movies = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  music = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
  ...
  class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'girls'
```

Story: Database is MariaDB+InnoDB and text fields may contain insanely large unicode poems.
So I've quickly run into this problem http://instantbadger.blogspot.ru/2013/01/mysql-row-size-too-large-when-saving.html

Problem: in MariDB there is no way to specify default ROW_FORMAT for all tables via variable (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9646)

Question: How can specify this option in Meta or migration file itself to make django add "ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED" to final SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a custom SQL migration operation inside a migration file like so:

```
operations = [
    ...
    migrations.RunSQL(""" YOUR SQL HERE """)
]
```

Because what you want can't be done with Django as-is, but you can manually add a line to the migration that alters the table, as shown above.

Note that this makes your project less flexible: in case you decide to migrate to a storage backend that doesn't support the operation, then you'll need to rewrite the migration. Also, when you change a model the changes are not reflected in handwritten SQL, which could potentially break things. Having said this, sometimes it's hard to get around a handwritten query.

Alternatively you could write you're own django package that adds this functionality to the model's Meta. This would also require writing a custom database backend, because as far as i know it's not possible to easily add custom database operations to existing database backends.